# I cannot access XFCE when launched via LightDM

Tags: xfce, lightdm, lfs, system-v

As a personal project I decided to start building a Linux From Scratch (System V Edition, 9.1) on a virtual machine. Everything went out correctly until the moment of entering the system through LightDM. After entering the username and password, a message appears on the screen saying that the connection was refused. I have tried to find information about the problem, but nothing is helpful. I also try using LXDM, but the same problem happened.

This is the message that appears:
[image]
*(Translation: Can't connect with the configuration server - Couldn't connect: Connection refused)*

I can get into XFCE by running startx and startxfce4. However, when I try to enter the xfce4-session or xfsettingsd commands, the same error appears on the screen:

```
Unable to init server: No se pudo conectar: Conexión rehusada
```

*(Translation: Couldn't connect: Connection refused)*

Please let me know in case more information is required.

This is the content of the Xorg.0.log:

```
[     7.858] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.7
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     7.858] Build Operating System: Linux 4.19.0-10-amd64 x86_64 
[     7.858] Current Operating System: Linux bluelinux 5.5.3 #4 SMP Thu Sep 24 01:13:21 UTC 2020 x86_64
[     7.858] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.5.3-lfs-9.1 root=/dev/sda3 ro
[     7.858] Build Date: 24 September 2020  12:54:30AM
[     7.858]  
[     7.858] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
[     7.858]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     7.858] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     7.858] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Sep 24 22:13:24 2020
[     8.022] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     8.056] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     8.056] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     8.056] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     8.056] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     8.056] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     8.056] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     8.056] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     8.056] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     8.056] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[     8.197] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/".
[     8.197]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     8.197]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/").
[     8.223] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/".
[     8.223]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     8.223]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/").
[     8.224] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/".
[     8.224]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     8.224]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/").
[     8.224] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/OTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/
[     8.224] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     8.224] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     8.224] (II) Loader magic: 0x616cc0
[     8.224] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     8.224]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     8.224]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[     8.224]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[     8.224]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[     8.224] (++) using VT number 7

[     8.224] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[     8.224] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     8.225] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 15ad:0405:15ad:0405 rev 0, Mem @ 0xf0000000/134217728, 0xf8000000/2097152, I/O @ 0x0000d010/16, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     8.225] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[     8.225] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     8.274] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     8.828] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.828]    compiled for 1.20.7, module version = 1.0.0
[     8.828]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[     8.828] (==) Matched vmware as autoconfigured driver 0
[     8.828] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[     8.828] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[     8.828] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[     8.828] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     8.828] (II) LoadModule: "vmware"
[     8.834] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so
```

This is the content of lightdm.log:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.30.0, UID=0 PID=610
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.17s] DEBUG: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation local (GLocalVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.27s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.29s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.30s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Could not run plymouth --ping: Failed to execute child process “plymouth” (No such file or directory)
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.30s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.30s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.30s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Launching X Server
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Launching process 626: /usr/bin/X :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.30s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+3.06s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+3.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
```

Comment: Does it work as root?

Comment: @rfmodulator It works as root when starting by startx or startxfce4, but by LigthDM, it doesn't work neither as root or normal user.

Comment: Did you install and configure `Linux-PAM?` Did you re-install `Shadow` afterwords?

Comment: @rfmodulator Yes, both of them. I just checked and I have configuration files as requested by the book.

Comment: Did you install `elogind`? And configure it ...including building a new kernel with the supporting options?

Comment: @rfmodulator Yes, I try to always install all the recommended dependencies throughout the installation process in the book.

Comment: @rfmodulator Yes, whenever I was asked to reconfigure the kernel I would do it and copy the necessary files back to `/boot` along with the documentation